# I am unable to save a component. (80040356) Unable to save item length cannot be less than zero

Tags: web8

Can anyone help me. I am trying to embed a data visualization and it get an error about the length being less than zero but I cannot find a length parameter anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community Kylo! There is a hotfix available with SDL for this.

You can refer to the following link for the [issue](https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/SolutionArticles/000005011?articleName=000008523). The hotfix information should be available [here](http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/).